# Removing Chromium browser from Debian 9 system

Tags: debian, browser

I've downloded Chromium version 80 in the form of a zip file. The extracted folder "chrome-linux" contains a 
script "chrome-wrapper" which when executed install the browser and put the logo on the desktop. I was able to launch and use the browser as expected. Now I'd like to remove it but don't know how. I couldn't find a script and Synaptic doesn't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `checkinstall`.

From `man checkinstall`:

```
       checkinstall is a program that monitors  an  installation  procedure  (such  as  make
       install,  install.sh  ),  and  creates a standard package for your distribution (cur‐
       rently deb, rpm and tgz packages are supported) that you  can  install  through  your
       distribution's package management system (dpkg, rpm or installpkg).
```

Running `checkinstall chrome-wrapper` will wrap around the installation-script, create a debian-package and install said package.

After that, you can just deinstall the package with `dpkg -r` or `apt remove` or whichever package manager you like best.

It is a good habit to ALWAYS use `checkinstall` with installation-scripts and `make install`.